# How are complex numbers $(a,b,c)$ located when $\frac{b-a}{c-a}=\frac{a-c}{b-c}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How are complex numbers $(a,b,c)$ located when $\frac{b-a}{c-a}=\frac{a-c}{b-c}$? I have know idea how to begin. I guess i should use the $arg(\frac{b-a}{c-a})$ and $arg(\frac{a-c}{b-c})$ but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

Let $re^{iu}=\frac{b-a}{c-a}=\frac{a-c}{b-c}.$

$\Leftrightarrow (c-a)=re^{iu}(b-a)$ and $(b-c)=re^{iu}(a-c).$

Let us now convert these relationships into equivalent vectorial expressions:

$\vec{AC}=H_r(R_a(\vec{AB}))$ and $\vec{CB}=H_r(R_a(\vec{CA}))$

where $R_a$ is rotation with (oriented) angle $a$ and $H_r$ is homothety with ratio $r$. This proves that

> points $A$, $B$, $C$ are arranged as a isosceles triangle with symmetry axis passing through $A$.

[image]